# I am getting this error Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT) in last testcase give that error

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

```
int solve(int H[],int n,int i,int prev)

{

    if(i>=n)

       return 0;

    if(dp[i][prev+1]!=-1)

      return dp[i][prev+1];

    int inc=0,exc=0;

    if(prev==-1)

    {

       inc=1+solve(H,n,i+1,i);

       exc=solve(H,n,i+1,prev);

    }

    if(prev!=-1)

    {

        if(H[prev]<H[i])

          inc=1+solve(H,n,i+1,i);

        exc = solve(H,n,i+1,prev);

    }

  return dp[i][prev+1]=max(inc,exc);



}

int removeStudents(int H[], int N) {

    // code here

    dp=vector<vector<int>>(N,vector<int>(N,-1));

      int ans = solve(H,N,0,-1);

   return N-ans;

}
```

};

N Students of different heights are attending an assembly. The heights of the students are represented by an array H[]. The problem is that if a student has less or equal height than the student standing in front of him, then he/she cannot see the assembly. Find the minimum number of students to be removed such that all the remaining students can see the assembly.